# Where have I gone wrong (using Stirling approximation and differentiation)?

Tags: calculus

I have to show that

$\frac{\partial ln(\omega)}{\partial n} = ln(\frac{(N-n)(N_i-n)}{n^2})$

And I know that $\omega = \frac{N_i!N!}{n!(N_i-n)!n!(N-n)!}$.

So to find and simplify $ln(\omega)$, I used the Stirling approximation:
$ln(x!) = xln(x) - x$.

So

$ln(\omega) = ln(N_i!) + ln(N!) - ln[(N_i-n)!] - 2ln(n!) - ln[(N-n)!]$

$= N_iln(N_i)-N_i +Nln(N) - N - (N_i-n)ln(N_i-n) + (N_i-n) -2nln(n) +2n - (N-n)ln(N-n) + (N-n)$

$=N_iln(N_i) + Nln(N) - N_iln(N_i-n)+nln(N_i-n) - 2nln(n) - Nln(N-n) + nln(N-n)$

Differentiating this doesn't give the required answer! It gives

$\frac{N_i}{N_i-n} + ln(N_i-n) - \frac{n}{N_i-n} -2ln(n) - 2 + \frac{N}{N-n} + ln(N-n) - \frac{n}{N-n}$

And that doesn't simplify to what I'm after. Unless differentiating is where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many equal signs that stand for approximations...

Comment: @ErickWong I don't know how to do an 'approximately equal to' sign in MathJax. I hoped people would know what I meant.

Comment: So you just silently chose not to mention it? :)  Use \approx in MathJax.  I don't know which of your equal signs are supposed to be an approximate one, else I would have fixed it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume we're actually supposed to treat the factorials using the gamma
function; otherwise taking a derivative with respect to $n$
does not make much sense.

In the formula you obtained,
$$
\frac{N_i}{N_i-n} + ln(N_i-n) - \frac{n}{N_i-n} -2ln(n) - 2 + \frac{N}{N-n} + ln(N-n) - \frac{n}{N-n},
$$
observe that
\begin{align}
\frac{N_i}{N_i-n} - \frac{n}{N_i-n} & = \frac{N_i-n}{N_i-n} = 1, \\
\frac{N}{N-n} - \frac{n}{N-n} & = \frac{N-n}{N-n} = 1, \\
1 + 1 - 2 & = 0.
\end{align}

That eliminates most of the terms of your expression.
Can you work with what's left?

The step that I would worry about is the initial Stirling's formula,
which after all is an *approximation.*

Comment: What is the gamma function? And thank you for pointing that out, I do actually get what I'm supposed to with that simplification!

Comment: The gamma function $\Gamma(x)$ is a function over the real numbers (complex numbers, if you prefer) related to the factorial $n!$ by $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html